# How to apply python syntax highlighter to a django model TextField

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x

I want to apply a syntax highlighter to a django TextField but unable to do so. Please suggest.

I have tried using AceWidget to textfield but it end up with below error:
    `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'`

```
class CodeHiglighter(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    h_code = models.TextField(widget=AceWidget)
```

I need to apply python syntax highlighter to TextField

Answer (score 3):

You need to use widget on your form not on model

```
class CodeHiglighter(forms.Form)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    h_code = forms.TextField(widget=AceWidget)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about AceWidget, but some tutorials I've been following use the pygments library which may help you. There's a django [example here](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/08/django-blog-project-12-adding-pygments-syntax-highlighting/).

Pygments [homepage example](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/#example).